# SELECT or JOIN using same column twice

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I have three tables: Employee, Secretary and Manager

#### Given Schema

The `Employee` table has the following columns:

- Employee_Number
- Name
- Home Address
- Telephone Number

The `Secretary` table contains:

- Secretary_Number
- Employee_Number (linked with foreign key to Employee table)
- Manager_Number (linked with foreign key to Manager table)

The `Manager` table contains:

- Manager_Number
- Employee_Number (linked with foreign key to Employee table)

#### What's required and what I tried

I am trying to do a JOIN so that I can see following columns:

- Secretary's Number
- Secretary's Name
- Manager's Number
- Manager's Name

I have the following join statement, which shows all the columns, and shows the *Secretary's name* and *number*, as well as the *Manager Number*:

```
SELECT
  SECRETARY.SECRETARY_NUMBER, 
  SECRETARY.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS SECRETARY_EMPLOYEE,
  EMPLOYEE.NAME AS SECRETARY_NAME,
  SECRETARY.MANAGER_NUMBER, 
  MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS MANAGER_EMPLOYEE,
  EMPLOYEE.NAME AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM SECRETARY, MANAGER, EMPLOYEE
WHERE SECRETARY.MANAGER_NUMBER = MANAGER.MANAGER_NUMBER
AND SECRETARY.SECRETARY_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
AND MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;
```

#### Problem

But I can't get the *Manager's Name* to show up, or not repeat the same info as *Secretary Name*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well asked question: clear structure, proper code-format, especially the __`Oracle` tag__ helps alot! One minor thing: SQL is better readable if _not ALL-CAPS_, e.g. enough to have keywords upper like `FROM secretary, manager, employee WHERE secretary.manager_number = ..`

Comment: Use the join syntax it is much cleaner, also try to use aliases so you don't have to type in long table names.  Finally you were close think this through - I posted an answer but try to understand why or how it works.  Remember secretaries have managers, and managers are employees.

Comment: Welcome to SE :^) In your case, you have 2 JOINS to the same table employee, so you would need to identify one of those as an alias and then refer to it, otherwise your SQL will be ambiguous. Why would you not use a normal JOIN instead of the WHERE clauses? You do need to think about what you want, though. If a secretary has no managers or a manager has no secretary, what do you want to show? If a secretary helps 3 managers, or a manager needs 3 secretaries...? I would think about your data structure first and then read up on the JOIN statement and ALIASes.

Comment: @Morten in this particular instance one Manager would supervise many Secretaries with the realtionship being obligatory on both ends. I changed my code to use aliases and joins instead of where and it works as intended now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  s.SECRETARY_NUMBER, 
  s.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS SECRETARY_EMPLOYEE,
  e.NAME AS SECRETARY_NAME,
  s.MANAGER_NUMBER, 
  m.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS MANAGER_EMPLOYEE,
  e2.NAME AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM 
  SECRETARY s
INNER JOIN
  EMPLOYEE e
ON
  e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = s.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
INNER JOIN
  MANAGER m
ON
  m.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = s.MANAGER_NUMBER
INNER JOIN
  EMPLOYEE e2
ON
 e2.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = m.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;
```